# Animation doesn't repeat correctly in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit

```
@objc private func updateCountdownLabel(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    self.progressWidthAnchor.constant = 0
    if let timeRemaining = notification.userInfo?["timeRemaining"] as? Int {
        self.secondsRemaining = timeRemaining
        self.animateProgress(width: 100, duration: 10)
    }
}

private func animateProgress(width: CGFloat, duration: Int) {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration),
                   delay: TimeInterval(LocalConstants.animationDelayDuration),
                   options: .curveLinear) {
            self.progressWidthAnchor.constant = width
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

I'm having a weird issue with my animation. At the moment I am trying to animate a bar decreasing/increasing but I need it to repeat every second.

For some reason it doesn't repeat the animation, the constraint jumps outside the view.

It works the first time, but the second time it doesn't work as you'd expect.

No constraint warnings are thrown.

Moving code around,
updating the layoutIfNeeded to various locations

Comment: There's nothing in the source code you provided that would trigger the animation every second, nor there's code that would change the constraint's constant back into its initial value.

Comment: the notification would cause the code to repeat, furthermore
self.progressWidthAnchor.constant = 0 
in updateCountdownLabel

Answer (score 0):

The cause of my animation not working correctly was due to

removeAllAnimations() not being called prior to the next UIView.animate code blo

Figured it out

Calling `removeAllAnimations` before executing the code again fixed my issue